# how to define port in test bench?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
module stimulus;
  wire [3:0] max,med,min;
  reg [3:0] a,b,c;
  reg cin;
  sorting_three three(max,med,min,a,b,c,cin);

  initial begin
    a=4'b0010;
    b=4'b1001;
    c=4'b1010;
    cin=1'b0;
  end
endmodule
```

The above code giving correct result after Simulation. When I try to view RTL schematic. Its is giving error like:

```
ERROR:Xst - "stimulus.v" line 22: Module  has no port.
-->

Total memory usage is 123976 kilobytes

Number of errors   :    1 (   0 filtered)
Number of warnings :    0 (   0 filtered)
Number of infos    :    0 (   0 filtered)


Process "Synthesis" failed
```

How to define port of stimulus( it is test bench)? I think wire and reg is sufficient to define input and output port. If it is not then what correction required to get correct RTL schematic.

Comment: You shouldn't be synthesizing a testbench anyway. A testbench module is meant to be used in simulation only, to represent parts of the application that are outside the module(s) being tested. Think about it -- a module that has no outputs synthesizes to zero logic, no matter how complex the code inside might be.

Answer (score 1):

All modules need a list of ports, for example

```
module mymodule(port_a, port_b);
```

For a test bench module this list is empty, but it still needs to be there:

```
module stimulus();
```

Comment: Not completely correct. You can have `module stimulus;` without the `()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is whatever tool you are using to draw an RTL schematic won't accept a module that isn't 100% synthesizable. A synthesizable RTL block must have input and output ports.